# Automatically add negative sign to user input (PLUNKER ATTACHED)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, forms, validation

http://plnkr.co/edit/v53QDV8604OwGc6VdVYw?p=preview

I have a very basic doubt which i am not able to figure out how to solve it. If you see the input field 'negative'- i have to take negative values from user.

User might enter '-34.45' , '-455' and so on. But if user enters '56' and goes to next input field, i want the entered field to update as '-56'

So i need to check first if negative sign is not there and then only add a negative sign. Any suggestions ?>

```
<html>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the number, check if it is under zero, if not, subtract from zero. Assign it back.

https://jsfiddle.net/subterrane/pnrmxhsv/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <label for="num">Negative</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="-52" id="num">
    </div>
</div>

    <script>
        document.querySelector('#num').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            var num = e.target.value;
            num = parseFloat(num, 10);
            if(!isNaN(num) && num > 0) num = 0 - num;
            e.target.value = num;
        })

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks wil. ur answer works fine too. can you check my answer too. if i was on the right track ?

Answer (score 0):

omg, i cant believe i will be able to answer my own question. it works perfectly fine for me. here is the code i tried and it worked well.

```
$scope.$watch(function ($scope) {
    if ($scope.params.speed != undefined && $scope.params.speed > 0) {
        $scope.params.speed = $scope.params.speed - (2 * $scope.params.speed );
    };

})
```